# Putting web links on the unity desktop

Tags: unity

I have been trying to put a web link on my desktop. Researching on this I have found that some urls can be just dragged and dropped.

When you do this with others you get a copy of the web page not a link and there is a third group that gives you a `COULD NOT DISPLAY "http whatever"` message.  Does anyone know the reason behind the three different results?

Comment: Where are you dragging links from? Do you mean just drag text with URL address, right? Please, provide examples of URL for each of the three mentioned cases. Also, where are you getting that message?

Comment: also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/443352/putting-web-links-on-the-unity-desktop

Comment: you have the right idea with the drag and drop.  examples are "https://idesk.aramark.net/login" which gives the "unable to display" message; "https://webmail.aramark.com" which works fine; and the address bar on this page which copies this page to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what drag-drop urls do. I would suggest you create a new file on your desktop with the extension `.desktop`. Then edit the file and put this in it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=<your name>
Type=Link
URL=https://<your url>
Icon=<this is optional>
```

Comment: this works fine for at least one type of web page but not all.  the confusion comes from why the web pages act differently.  judging from the numerous posts on the same general subject, it would seem this is a much misunderstood issue.

Comment: There is cross-OS consistent and well-defined behaviour for dragging and dropping web links onto desktops(, namely it should create an icon which double-clicked would open the URL in the default browser), and also for dragging and dropping icons on the desktop surface(, a common way to move icons around). Unity, counterintuitively enough copies the contents and creates .html files. Very useful indeed. Why can't unity just follow that cross-OS behaviour? Users expect that. You want new users? Fix that.